# How to get docker app logs to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

Is there any way to stream/push docker app logs to S3 bucket? 
I know following 2 ways

1. Configure cloud watch logs/stream - All logs (both info & Error logs) are getting merged in this approach
2. Configure graylogs2 to push every log message and collect and then push to S3 bucket - Need to maintain graylogs2  app.

I am looking for any easy way to push docker app/error logs S3 Bucket

Thanks

Comment: By docker app, you mean container logs or something else?

Comment: By logs I mean log4j info and error logs specific to app deployed in docker.

Comment: Are you seeing approach 1 as inconvenient?. Do you have a specific need to push logs to S3 instead of cloudwatch?

Comment: No... Above 2 approaches are not good... I am looking for other approach other than above mentioned 2 approaches...

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, though it's hard to tell for your case, is to run logstash in a separate container, and have your app direct logs to logstash. Since [*Logstash’s logging framework is based on Log4j 2 framework*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logging.html), it will likely be familiar to you. A plugin [already exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) for logstash to push to S3 on your behalf.

You can [configure your existing log4j2](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-input-log4j2/3.3) to emit to a port that logstash is running on.

If even this is considered too much maintenance for you, your best solution is probably just setting up a cron to run [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).